# Qual a diferença entre "ficção" e "não ficção"?

Tags: literatura

Ao andar pelas livrarias ou navegar por elas via internet, é comum encontrarmos as seções *Ficção* e *Não Ficção*. Mas, afinal de contas, qual a diferença entre eles?

Livros que encontrei na parte *Ficção*:

- O pequeno príncipe
- Maus
- Dom Casmurro

Livros que encontrei na parte *Não Ficção*:

- Depois de Auschwitz
- A história do mundo para quem tem pressa
- A Arte da guerra

Comment: O que nas definições dos dicionários não lhe é claro? (Por exemplo, [ficção](https://dicionario.priberam.org/fic%C3%A7%C3%A3o): "Criação de carácter artístico, baseada na imaginação, mesmo se idealizada a partir de dados reais."; [não ficção](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/n%C3%A3o%20fic%C3%A7%C3%A3o): "conjunto de obras literárias em que se integram textos que não exploram personagens ou acontecimentos imaginados, como o ensaio ou a crítica".)

Comment: Não se trata de uma pergunta sobre o português.

Answer (score 1):

A ficção é uma narrativa imaginária, irreal, ou para redefinir obras criadas a partir da imaginação.

A não-ficção é uma narrativa factual sobre a realidade.